# how to show standard timing format result in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a function like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[podiumsummerytime] (@dec NUMERIC(18, 2)) RETURNS Varchar(50) 
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE
 @hour decimal(18,2),
      @Mns decimal(18,2)


 DECLARE @Average  Varchar(50) 
select @hour=CONVERT(int,@dec/60/60)
 SELECT @Mns = convert(int, (@dec / 60) - (@hour * 60 ));

 SELECT @Average = (case when @hour = 0 then ''
                     when @hour < 10 then '0' + cast(@hour as varchar(255)) + 'hr:'
                     else cast(@hour as varchar(255)) + 'hr:'
                end) +
               (case when @mns < 10 then '0' + cast(@mns as varchar(255)) + 'Mn:'
                     else cast(@mns as varchar(255))+ 'Mn'
                end)
RETURN @Average 
END
```

and i have a query like this:

```
select  dbo.podiumsummerytime(
                convert(decimal(10,1),
                    avg(convert(numeric(18,2), datediff(ss, t.dtime, t.PAICdate  ))))

            ) as Avgparkingtime,
```

my result is getting like this:

```
Avgparkingtime
02.00hr:20.00min
```

if we have 1 hour now showing 1,instead of this i have to show 01.and if have 5 minutes showing 5,instead of that i have to show 05
so my expected out put like this:

```
Avgparkingtime
01hr:20Mn
```

any help is very appreciable

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to zero pad numbers.  Because of the range, this is probably most easily done with `case`:

```
 SELECT @Average = (case when @hour = 0 then ''
                         when @hour < 10 then '0' + cast(@hour as varchar(255)) + 'hr:'
                         else cast(@hour as varchar(255)) + 'hr:'
                    end) +
                   (case when @min < 10 then '0' + cast(@mns as varchar(255)) + 'Mn:'
                         else cast(@mns as varchar(255) + 'Mn'
                    end) /* +
                   (case when @second < 10 then '0' + cast(@second as varchar(255))
                         else cast(@second as varchar(255))
                    end) */;
```

However, I think you should just use the format "HH:MM:SS".  This is a standard format, easily understandable, and can be generated using `convert()`.

Comment: after editing my function like this: i try to run my stored procedure..but getting null value

Comment: @user3106114 . . . Probably because you never set `@second` to any value and I included it even though it was commented out.

Comment: sir i am getting result like this: 02.00hr:20.00min,,i want result 02hr:20min